# How _ts change in DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a question regarding the _ts field within the documentdb. How is it determined? My understanding is that when a document is added/altered it gets a new _ts. Are there any chance that two documents have the same _ts? If so, does it happen only if those documents are added at the exact time (in terms of milli second).

Answer (score 28):

`_ts` is a system property denoting when a document was last updated (e.g. create or replace).

`_ts` is represented as a [POSIX or epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) value. In other words, its the number of seconds (not milliseconds) that have elapsed since 00:00:00 (UTC), 1 January 1970.

It is possible to have the same `_ts` value across multiple documents when there are multiple documents written/updated during the same second.

Comment: This means that you could see another document with the same _ts. But, is it at least guaranteed (with session consistency) that you'll never see a lower _ts? If so, then an incremental update could use "greater than or equal to" and deal with duplicates from the last read (idempotency). Or is that not even guaranteed?

Comment: Practically, speaking you should never see a lower `_ts` value for a given partition... but this is something that is not guaranteed.

Comment: Here's a devblog source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/new-date-and-time-system-functions/

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew Liu has mentioned the `_ts` property shows the **date and time** which the document was **last updated.**

the following function can be used to get the time in `_ts`  in a human readable format `TimestampToDateTime(c._ts*1000)`.

Example :

```
SELECT c.FirstName , TimestampToDateTime(c._ts*1000) AS 'time' FROM Person c
```

Comment: If anybody is wondering why you multiply `_ts` by 1000 in that query: `_ts` is in **seconds** in CosmosDB, but [TimestampToDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/timestamptodatetime) works in **milliseconds**.

Comment: Thanks for that. Really good to find that function.